# Secure php -> Ajax delete item based on id

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm building an app and I want the users to be able to delete some items.

I got this code for the delete button

```
<a class='delete_item' id='".$rs['id']."'><i class='icon-cancel'> </i></a>
```

The js file is called upon click

```
...
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'set_order.php',
  data:'delete_item='+item_id,
  beforeSend: function() {
        },
  success:function() {
    window.location.reload(true)
  }
});
...
```

The set_order.php file opens and this code is processed

```
if($_POST['delete_item']) {
$id = $_POST['delete_item'];
$sql = "DELETE from list_items where ID = $id";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
}
```

Everything works fine, but it's not secured at all :) If the user inspects the page and changes the value of "id" as shown in this picture
[image]

And hits the "delete" button, the item with the id that the user changed will be deleted instead of the original id.

What is the best way to check the data?

Comment: Are users allowed to delete any item?

Comment: @iyop45 Only the items they added, I select them from the Database and display the close button only to the user that created them.

Comment: Establish an "Authorizer" in your backend that checks if that user is allowed to delete that specific item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you receive the request to delete an item check that they own the item and if they don't, don't delete it.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete_item'])){
    if(userOwnsItem($_SESSION['id'], $_POST['delete_item']){
       // Valid request
    }else{
       // Invalid request
    }
}
```

Where `$_SESSION['id']` is the id of the user and the function `userOwnsItem` performs a query on the item and checks if the owner has the same id as the user.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not AJAX because you reload the page. You should edit the DOM elements based on responses and calls, not manually reloading. In fact if you do DELETE option in php it will be way better and secure to do it the normal way, just redirect to some page and on success delete you redirect somewhere or back to the same page. If you want DO a real ajax request and want to secure the action and prevent other users for doing this there are a lot of methods and ways. You can do check if the users is ALLOWED to delete the requested id, you can AUTHORIZE certain users to be able to do this action. The most important of all is the data transfer. You should never ever let data that is not encrypted pass. So you should basically do this:

1. Check if user can access the function and the page
2. Check if user owns what he wants to remove
3. Send the id in a way it's not clear what it is - a lot of functions do so in php manual. The best way is to use your own 2 way algo - encrypt / decrypt by using special words ( salt ).

Answer (score -1):

insert "echo $sql;" on php end test your SQL is correct

Comment: How does this stop a malicious user?